# mutliple set timeouts running at once

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

so, i have a for loop that I want to run multiple set timeouts at once so it can continually check if it is a certain time for multiple times. i can't just check for all multiple times all at once, the check needs to repeat after different amounts of time. it only continues to repeat the last iteration of the loop, the last dict in lat.

my approach simplified a bit:

```
lat = list of dictionaries with some values that differentiate them + times
for(i = 0; i< lat.length; i++){

if(lat[i][differentiate value]) = {

function checktime(){
   if(currenttime != lat[i]){
setTimeout(checktime,30000)
}
else{
console.log("yay the time is right!")
}

}

else if(lat[i][differentiate value]) = {

function checktime(){
   if(currenttime != lat[i]){
setTimeout(checktime,50000)
}
else{
console.log("yay the time is right!")
}

}

}
```

How would I go about making this (its for a notification app)

original code:
(each value in later looks like [[75,null,[7,28,2021]], null,[[9,52,"p"]],"e&r"] with the amount of notifications, a preset date, the date for these reminders to be on, by time, which would be the first if, and the array of at times. for testing I had 2 laters with 2 different at times):

```
 chrome.storage.sync.get('later', function(data){
        if (data.later !== null){
        var lat = data.later;
        
        for(i = 0; i< lat.length; i++){
            var currentDict = lat[i];
            
                if(currentDict['notis'][1] !== null){
                    console.log("cheese")
                    var by = currentDict['notis'][1];
                    console.log(by)

                    const d = new Date();
                        var hr = d.getHours();
                        var min = d.getMinutes();
                        var sec = d.getSeconds();
                        
                        var da = currentDict['notis'][0][2][1];
                        var mo = currentDict['notis'][0][2][0];
                        var ye = currentDict['notis'][0][2][2]
                        var h = by[0];
                        var m = by[1];
                        var ampm = by[2];
                        if(ampm == "p"){
                        h = h + 12;
                        }

                        var byMS = h*3600000 + m*60000;
                        var currentMS = hr*3600000 + min*60000 + sec*1000;

                        //check if right date then check if time is lesss than

                    
                    function checkdate(){
                        var day = d.getDate();
                        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                        var year = d.getFullYear();
                        if(da == day && mo == month && ye == year){
                            var amt = 0;
                            function checktime(){
                            if(byMS >= currentMS){
                                //noti and delete
                                var int = setInterval(function(){

                                    chrome.notifications.create({
                                        title: currentDict['name'],
                                        message: "do da " + currentDict['name'],
                                        iconUrl: "logo.png",
                                        type: "basic"
                                
                                    })
    
                                    amt++
                                    console.log(amt)
                                    const dddd = new Date();
                                    console.log(dddd.getMinutes() + " / " + dddd.getSeconds())
                                    if(amt >= currentDict['notis'][0][0]){
                                        clearInterval(int)
                                        console.log("done")
                                        //ju finish taht
                                        console.log(lat)
                                            lat.splice(lat.indexOf(currentDict),1)
                                            console.log(lat)
                                            chrome.storage.sync.set({'later': lat})
                                        
                                    }
                                }, (byMS-currentMS)/currentDict['notis'][0][0])
                            }
                            else{
                                setTimeout(checktime,30000)
                            }
                        }
                        checktime();
                        }
                        else{
                            setTimeout(checkdate,66400000)
                        }
                    }
                    checkdate();
                }
                else if(currentDict['notis'][2] !== null){
                    

                    console.log("cheese")
                    var at = currentDict['notis'][2];
                    console.log(at)
                    
                    var arrayat = [];
                for(j = 0; j<= at.length-1; j++){
                    var atcycle = at[j];
                    console.log(atcycle)
                    const ddd = new Date();
                    var hr = ddd.getHours();
                    var min = ddd.getMinutes();
                    
                    var da = currentDict['notis'][0][2][1];
                    var mo = currentDict['notis'][0][2][0];
                    var ye = currentDict['notis'][0][2][2]
                    var hrat = atcycle[0];
                    var minat = atcycle[1];
                    var ampm = atcycle[2];
                    if(ampm == "p"){
                    hrat = hrat + 12;
                    }
                    console.log(hrat + "/" + minat + "/" + ampm)
                    if(hr <= hrat){
                           
                        var temparray = [];
                        temparray.push(hrat)
                        temparray.push(minat)
                        arrayat.push(temparray);
                        console.log(arrayat)
                         }
                          
                    else if(hr == hrat){
                            if(min<minat){
                                var temparray = [];
                                temparray.push(hrat)
                                temparray.push(minat)
                                arrayat.push(temparray);
                                console.log(arrayat)}
                                }       
                        }      
                        console.log(arrayat.length)     
                    function checkdate(){
                        console.log(arrayat.length)
                        console.log("date")
                        const d = new Date();
                        var day = d.getDate();
                        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                        var year = d.getFullYear();
                        if(da == day && mo == month && ye == year){
                            function check(){
                                console.log(arrayat.length)
                                console.log("check")
                                for(l=0; l<arrayat.length; l++){
                                    console.log(arrayat.length)
                                const dd = new Date();
                                var hr = dd.getHours();
                                var min = dd.getMinutes();
                                console.log(arrayat[l][1])
                                console.log(min)
                                if(arrayat[l][0] == hr && arrayat[l][1] == min ){ //at one of the times
                                    console.log(arrayat)
                                    arrayat.splice(l,1)
                                    console.log(arrayat)
                                    if(arrayat.length == 0){
                                        lat.splice(lat.indexOf(currentDict),1)
                                        chrome.storage.sync.set({'later': lat})
                                        console.log(lat)
                
                                    }
                                    chrome.notifications.create({
                                        title: currentDict['name'],
                                        message: "do da " + currentDict['name'],
                                        iconUrl: "logo.png",
                                        type: "basic"
                                
                                    })
                                    //add noti with name and delete it
                                    console.log(arrayat)
                                    check();
                                     }
                                }
                                console.log(arrayat.length)
                                if(arrayat.length !== 0){
                                    console.log("and repeat")
                                    setTimeout(check,15000);//SETINTERVAL INSTEAD? ANDCLEAR
                                }
                                
                            }
                            check();
                            }
                            else{
                            setTimeout(checkdate,66400000)
                            }
                     }
                     checkdate();
                             
                }

                
            }
           }
          
    })
    }
```

Comment: Atleast paste the formatted and correct code.

Comment: its a lot and its kind of arbitrary but sure

Comment: Post valid javascript, even if it's not your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. You know the times, so you know how far off they are in time. You don't need to check over and over again if the time has arrived. Instead work out how many milliseconds until the time in question, then set a timeout for that time.

Comment: oh yeah that's smart ill rework the code to test that tomorrow

Comment: Please mark as answer if it works out for you, thanks.

Comment: actually, wouldnt that still run into the same problem of timeouts of waiting for the timeout to be done before executing the next timeout in the for loop? rlly gotta run now ill see it in the morning, and ofc ill mark as answer

Comment: timeouts are async - so no. You can set all the timeouts inside a for loop, and they will all fire at the right time.

Comment: this worked like a charm, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to pass different functions to each `setTimeout()`:

```
function checktime1(){
   if(currenttime != lat[i]){
       setTimeout(checktime1,30000)
   }
   else{
       console.log("yay the time is right!")
   }
}

function checktime2(){
   if(currenttime != lat[i]){
       setTimeout(checktime2,50000)
   }
   else{
       console.log("yay the time is right!")
   } 
}
```

However, this is obviously not scalable. If you have lots of timeouts you will be writing lots of duplicate functions. Worse, if you have a dynamic number of timeouts this won't solve your problem.

Fortunately, javascript lets us declare functions inside another function:

```
function checktime(timeout){

    function loop () {
        if(currenttime != lat[i]){
            setTimeout(loop,timeout)
        }
        else{
            console.log("yay the time is right!")
        }
    }
    loop();
}
```

This allows you to dynamically create functions as needed:

```
checktime(30000);
checktime(50000);
```

If you need to pass arguments to each timeouts (eg. if you need to display custom alerts) you can just pass it to your outer function and it will be captured in a closure:

```
function checktime(timeout, message){

    function loop () {
        if(currenttime != lat[i]){
            setTimeout(loop,timeout)
        }
        else{
            console.log(message)
        }
    }
    loop();
}
```

Then you can do:

```
checktime(30000, "Yay, the time is right for timer 1");
checktime(50000, "Yay, the time is right for timer 2");
```

Similarly, if you need to execute custom logic for each timer you can also pass it as an argument (callback):

```
function checktime(timeout, callback){

    function loop () {
        if(currenttime != lat[i]){
            setTimeout(loop,timeout);
        }
        else{
            console.log("yay the time is right!");

            callback(); // <----------------- execute custom logic
        }
    }
    loop();
}
```

Which you can use like:

```
checktime(30000, () -> console.log("TIMER 1"));
checktime(50000, () -> alert("TIMER 2"));
```

Comment: where would i call checktime in the context of the for loop and ifs?

Comment: Hmm.. so you don't want to execute the setTimeout immediately?

Comment: Where do you call your `checktime()`?

Comment: i dont quite understand your approach, ill need to test it tomorrow morning since I gtg rn. ill get back to you then. ty tho :D